# How to resolve : use of JdbcTemplate.query(RowMapper;)Ljava/util/List; can be vulnerable to SQL injection (with Spring JDBC)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sonarqube, stringbuilder

Here is complete error :

```
This use of org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.query
(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper;)Ljava/util/List; 
can be vulnerable to SQL injection (with Spring JDBC)
```

Here is the reason/solution:

```
The input values included in SQL queries need to be passed in safely. 
Bind variables in prepared statements can be used to easily mitigate the risk of SQL injection.
```

Here is my query,

```java
 StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
 query.append("SELECT * from Events EVNT")
      .append(" WHERE EVNT.Roll IN ( '5', '1') AND EVNTDemo.Roll is null ")
      .append(" AND date(EVNT.Updt) between ")
      .append("date('").append(getTMyDate()) .append("') AND  CURRENT DATE-10 DAY")
```

How can I assign "?" to my query and pass the whole where condition as an argument object. Is there any other way to Fix this SONARQUBE ISSUE

```java
  final Object[] args = new Object[] {.....}
  result = jdbcTemplate.query(query, args, new MyMapper());
```

Edit 1  :

```java
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
 query.append("SELECT * from Events EVNT")
      .append(" WHERE EVNT.Roll IN ( '5', '1') AND EVNTDemo.Roll is null ")
      .append(" AND date(EVNT.Updt) between ")
      .append("date('").append("?").append("') AND  CURRENT DATE-10 DAY")

  final Object[] args = new Object[]{getTs()}; 
  result = jdbcTemplate.query(query, args, new MyMapper());
```

I am getting '?' appended in my query , where am I making mistake? Could anyone please point it out

Comment: The idea is not to pass the whole where clause, just not to put any string values directly into your SQL. Use a ? for the value of getTMyDate().

Comment: Thanks @tgdavies, I coded as per your comment, but I am not getting my value from the function. Please have a look at my edit .